# How to make PDFs in android by using the SQ L-LIGHT DB values

Tags: android

I want to generate a PDF file using the values of the db and display as a table, is there a way to do this thing.i'm using droidText.0.2.jar file

Comment: possible duplicate of [create pdf file programmatically on android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115921/create-pdf-file-programmatically-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the button click add two method as for create the pdf and open it like this

```
Button pdf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_searchcustomer_pdf_Isuru);
    dbHelper = new DBCreater(this);
    dbHelper.open();
    pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            createCustomerReport(s1);
            opencustomerReport();


        }});
```

i use this method to get values from the db.it's on a class call DBcreater

```
public String getCustomerDataForDELPdf(String s1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();

         String selectQuery = "select  cus_id,_id,customer_location,customer_phon,customer_shop,customer_email,customer_address,customer_name,customer_rep from Customer where customer_delear= '"+s1+"'" ; 
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
         String result="";
         int iid=c.getColumnIndex(Key_customer_CId);
         int iname=c.getColumnIndex(Key_customer_Name);
         int iaddress=c.getColumnIndex(Key_customer_Address);
         int icmp=c.getColumnIndex(Key_customer_Shop);
         int icity=c.getColumnIndex(Key_customer_Location);
         int iemail=c.getColumnIndex(Key_customer_Email);
         int iphon=c.getColumnIndex(Key_customer_Phon);
         int irep=c.getColumnIndex(Key_customer_Rep);
         for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
             result=result+c.getString(iid)+"*"+c.getString(icmp)+"*"+c.getString(iname)+"*"+c.getString(icity)+"*"+c.getString(iaddress)+"*"+c.getString(iemail)+"*"+c.getString(iphon)+"*"+c.getString(irep)+"*";
         }
         db.close();
         return result;
    }
```

this is my createCustomerReport(s1); method's cord

```
private void createCustomerReport(String s1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Document doc  =new Document();
                try {
                    //give the part for the doc
                    String parth = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";
                    //make object from file
                    File dir = new File(parth);
                    //make new pdf if not extit
                    if(!dir.exists())
                        dir.mkdir();
                    //
                    File file = new File(dir,"DelCusReport.pdf");
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);
                    doc.open();
                    String logger="Document Created by "+s1+" ";                                               //add the date to pdf
                    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                    String am_pm = (cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==0)?"AM":"PM";
                    String pdfheder=logger+" Date  "+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"/"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"        Created on  "+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+" : "+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" : "+cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)+" "+am_pm +"";
                    Paragraph p1= new Paragraph(pdfheder);
                    Font paraFont = new Font(Font.HELVETICA);
                    paraFont.setSize(36);
                    paraFont.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                    p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    p1.setFont(paraFont);
                    doc.add(p1);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.cusdatareport);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

                    //add image to document
                    doc.add(myImg);
                    Phrase footerText = new Phrase("Copy righs for jenasana groupes");
                    HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
                    doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

                    //make the table and give column names for that 
                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
                    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Id"));
                    c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(5);
                    table.addCell(c1);
                    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Company"));
                    c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(5);
                    table.addCell(c1);
                    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Name"));
                    c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(5);
                    table.addCell(c1);
                    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer City"));
                    c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(5);
                    table.addCell(c1);
                    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Address"));
                    c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(5);
                    table.addCell(c1);
                    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Email"));
                    c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(5);
                    table.addCell(c1);
                    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Phon"));
                    c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(5);
                    table.addCell(c1);
                    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Rep"));
                    c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(5);
                    table.addCell(c1);
                    table.setHeaderRows(1);
                    DBCreater db = new DBCreater(SearchCustomer.this);
                    db.openforread();
                    //db.getdata();      // getting the db values for the pdf
                    String dataset=db.getCustomerDataForDELPdf(s1);
                    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(dataset,"*");
                    String s11,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8;
                    while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
                        s11 = token.nextToken();
                        table.addCell(s11);
                        s2 = token.nextToken();
                        table.addCell(s2);
                        s3 = token.nextToken();
                        table.addCell(s3);
                        s4 = token.nextToken();
                        table.addCell(s4);
                        s5 = token.nextToken();
                        table.addCell(s5);
                        s6 = token.nextToken();
                        table.addCell(s6);
                        s7 = token.nextToken();
                        table.addCell(s7);
                        s8 = token.nextToken();
                        table.addCell(s8);
                        //add the values for the columns in the PDF table

                    }
                    //Anchor anc = new Anchor();
                    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
                    //Selection subcatpart = 
                    preface.add(table);
                                           //put the table to paragraph
                    doc.add(preface);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (DocumentException de) {
                    Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
                } 
                finally
                {
                    doc.close();
                }

        }
```

this is the cord for opencustomerReport(); method

```
private void opencustomerReport() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";
                            //use the same name you give when you creating the pdf
            File file = new File(path, "DelCusReport.pdf");
            intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" );
            startActivity(intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" ));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            Intent target = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
            try {
                startActivity(target);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("PDFCreator", "ActivityNotFoundException:" + e);
            }

        }
```

also add this to the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

also you must have a pdf viewer instal on your device to view the pdf

i think this can help to  solve your question

http://handtostandincordingfromisuruudith.blogspot.com/2014/06/generate-pdf-report-in-android-using.html

[Click for more on PDF on Anroid](http://mycodingworld1.blogspot.com/2014/06/generate-pdf-report-in-android-using.html)